# How to save data library to csv file.

Tags: csv, export, export-to-csv

So I have been trying to upload data that I got from a JSON library using an API key to a csv file so that I may manipulate in excel. Whenever I enter the command I get the following error.What am I doing incorrectly?

```
>>> with open("output_data.csv","w") as out_file:
...     for i in range(len(name)):
...             print i
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output_data.csv'
>>>
```